# converting html to pdf through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, pdf-generation

I am new to Javascript and HTML, I am building an application in PhoneGap and a PDF converter is part of my project. For this I have referred to [this](http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf) link, when I install this app on-device and run it I get an exception `ActivityNotFound` and on logcat an error message as:

```
03-28 17:41:39.406: E/Cordova(1781): Error loading url data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwI.... and so on
```

My `HTML` code is as follows:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsPDF</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        body {
            padding: 30px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        pre {
            border: 1px dotted #ccc;
            background: #f7f7f7;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 0.7em;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-top: 1em;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jspdf.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>jsPDF Demos</h1>

<p>Examples for using jsPDF with Data URIs below. Go <a href="http://jspdf.googlecode.com/">back to project homepage</a>.</p>

<h2>Simple Two-page Text Document</h2>
<pre>var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

// Output as Data URI
doc.output('datauri');</pre>
<a href="javascript:demo1()">Run Code</a>





<script type="text/javascript">

function demo1() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

    // Output as Data URI
    doc.output('datauri');
}


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Google Analytics

var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2746979-4");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the `ActivityNotFound` Exception is because I don't have a PDF reader on my device or do I have to write something more in my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"So the ActivityNotFound Exception is because i don't hv pdf reader in my device or do i hv to write something more to my code."* Why don't you install one and find out?

Comment: i had checked by installing pdf reader in my device but still it is not opening. in log cat i found that application is calling an implicit intent android.intent.action.VIEW this means application is opening browser and according to my knowledge i know that in android we cannot open a local file in browser so how to open generated pdf file...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have no Activity that can handle the mime type application/pdf    - in other words you are correct you need a pdf reader.

Comment: i hv checked it by installing pdf reader in my device but still i'm getting same error

Comment: Ok - does this code work on your desktop if so in which browsers ? - the data url is not supported on all browsers, this may be a problem with the phones default browser.

Comment: yes this code is working on desktop but only on chrome it is not working on mozilla and internet explorer. so now what to do to run it in phone default browser ...?